How the struct 'param_traits' is defined in OpenCL?
In OpenCL's C++ header file, line 1611, there is code as below:
template <typename enum_type, cl_int Name>
struct param_traits {};

#define CL_HPP_DECLARE_PARAM_TRAITS_(token, param_name, T) \
struct token;                                        \
template<>                                           \
struct param_traits<detail:: token,param_name>       \
{                                                    \
    enum { value = param_name };                     \
    typedef T param_type;                            \
};

It first defines a struct template. Then it defines a macro. It seems when the macro is expanded, it will specialize the struct. It's strange   that it add members into the structure also. I'm not very familiar with the newer C++ standard. So, how the code works here?

"it will specialize the struct. It's strange that it add members into the structure" - It does neither if you talk about token. If you talk about param_traits, it is a specialization of a class template - and then why is defining what members/type definitions it should have an issue?

param_traits<X, Y>::value will work only when X and Y are "supported" types, otherwise you end up with the main template which has no value nor param_type. Do you know what traits are for? If not, start e.g. here.

This has nothing to do with any "newer" standard - it is exactly the same as in the first standard from 1998.

@TedLyngmo I think I missed something. The first struct template has no members, and no 'typedef' s in it. But the second 'specialized' version has 'typedef's in it. If this is allowed by the language standard, then my question get answered.

@diverger Yes it is. That's what specialization is. template <class T> struct foo; template<> struct foo<int> { using type = something; }; specializes foo<int> (leaving the primary class template impossible to instantiate in this example).

A specialization does not need to have any relation with the primary template. In fact the latter can be left completely undefined as Ted demonstrates.

@TedLyngmo Here the added are 'enum' and 'typedef', I know they are allowed now. I think adding members variables such as 'int xxx;' is now allowed, right?

@diverger Absolutely. As WeijunZhou said, the specialization doesn't really have to have any relation with the primary (other than by normal language rules / template deduction / resolution stuff).

@TedLyngmo Do you mean I can modify the member of the origin template, and add any new member variables ?

@diverger No, the specialization is its own separate thing. The specialization does not contain anything from the primary template, except the class template name.

You may just as well think of the primary template as another specialization, one that is used if resolution against other specializations fails, if it helps. It is not special in any way. And as molbdnilo comments, there's nothing "now" about it. It has been always like this.

@rustyx The link is helpful indeed.

It seems I had some confusions about the template and it's 'specialization'. The specialized template may do more 'changes' to the original one than I thought, as long as they have the same name.
